# Can the ErrorInsight cache be cleared without reloading the project (group)?

Tags: delphi, caching, delphi-xe2, error-detection

When I work an a project group and make changes to a package that is used by the main program ErrorInsight fails to automatically update itself.

A similar issue can be seen in Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, when you change something in the data model, SSMS doesn't immediatly catch up with the changes.

In SSMS there is a menu command and keystroke (CTRL+SHIFT+R) that will reload the IntelliSense cache.

In RAD Studio I have to close the project group and reload it to get the ErrorInsight cache in sync.

Is there a better way to force ErrorInsight to update it's identifier cache?

Comment: I read somewhere this could be done by toggling the _Error insight_ check in _Tools -> Editor Options -> Code Insight_ and closing the _Options_ dialog afterwards (you'd need to do it one time for disabling and a second time for reenabling). Did you try that?

Comment: @GuillemVicens I just tried that, it doesn't work.

Comment: I find sometimes a clean -> compile (or clean->build) works... sometimes.

Comment: @J... I've seen that as well, but unsurprisingly code is not always in a buildable state, ...

Comment: well... I suppose if the compiler can't build it, it's hard to know what links to what, no? I guess we can only hope that the Intellisense guys end up working for Embarcadero some day.

Comment: @J... The ErrorInsight parser already has error recovery, so that's not the problem here. The problem is that it won't rebuild it's identifier cache across projects, unless a correct build or project reload has taken place.